# setup.py how to install package

Tags: python

I was trying to run this package:
https://github.com/THECRUSTIEST/ImToAPT
But I can not figure out how to run the package by following the guide.

I tried to configure the package by doing this command:

```
python setup.py install
```

I would like to get as a guide the wav file from the program:

Guide:
    import ImToAPT as APT

Convert any image (x<909):

```
sig = APT.iToSig('img.png', sRate=44100, mod=1)
```

Yields a signal object which is a 2400 Hz carrier amplitude-modulated by image. Includes sync markers and pre-scan white/black space per APT standard. mod sets the modulation percentage (0-1). Default is 100% modulation (1) because moduation <100% requires normalization after signal reception.
Convert an already imported object to an APT signal:

```
sig = APT.aToSig(img, sRate=44100, mod=1)
```

where img is a PIL image object or an RGBA or 2D Numpy array.
Export a signal to file:

```
sig.export('out.wav')
```

Signal is exported to a .wav file. Filename, of course, can be changed to whatever you like.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: I would like to get as a guide the wav file from the program.                                       But following the guide I wrote above I can not get the .wav file

Comment: I guess you want to run those commands they gave there right, then in your terminal just type python, then put in the line by line they gave there.

Comment: @SammyJ Like: python import ImToAPT as APT ?

Comment: no no, first type python in the terminal, you will get like >>> line in the terminal, you must type import ImToAPT there.

Comment: @SammyJ Understood, the only thing that the module does not exist, the package on github has a fiel called setup.py which I believe is needed to install the PIP package

Comment: @GionataDonati sorry I did not get what you're trying to say

Comment: @SammyJ  The github package (link above) contains a file called setup.py.
If I do as you told me (line by line from the terminal) it tells me:
ImportError: No module named ImToAPT

Comment: Did the python setup.py command install the package without any errors? else you would not get this message.

Comment: bash-3.2# python setup.py install
running install
running bdist_egg
running egg_info
creating ImToAPT.egg-info
writing requirements to ImToAPT.egg-info/requires.txt
writing ImToAPT.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing top-level names to ImToAPT.egg-info/top_level.txt
writing dependency_links to ImToAPT.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
writing manifest file 'ImToAPT.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
error: package directory 'ImToAPT' does not exist